# Manage list using data tables plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using [DataTables](http://datatables.net/) plugin to have sorting and paging on the tables. 
But plugin is not working as expected (at least for me) when I try to submit the form while using paging.

For ex: If total records is 14 and page size is 10, and when I navigate to page 2 and submit the page, only 4 records are posted to server instead of 14.

I assumed plugin is dynamically performing the operations without disturbing the content but its not the case, html table is regenerated when I navigate to other page, thus losing page 1 markup/content.

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I missed the documentation and also a thread which might help others as well.

[Pagination with selected check boxes. Checkboxes will only work on current pagination page. jQuery datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020574/pagination-with-selected-check-boxes-checkboxes-will-only-work-on-current-pagin)