# Checkboxes will only work on current pagination page in jQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, datatable

I am using jquery data table for listing my content which have checkbox selection and selected content post the data but in submitted form only current page data sent.

My Data table code is:

```
$('#select').dataTable( {
        "order": [[ 2, "desc" ]],
        "lengthMenu": [[50, -1], [50, "All"]],
        "columnDefs": [
                { orderable: false, targets: [0, 1, 3, 5] },
                { "width": "20px", "targets": [0, 1] },
                { "width": "80px", "targets": [5] }
        ],

});
```

When I click on submit, it only submit the array of checkboxes for the current page values.

I have referred this link already [Pagination with selected check boxes. Checkboxes will only work on current pagination page. jQuery datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020574/pagination-with-selected-check-boxes-checkboxes-will-only-work-on-current-pagin) but solution provided overthere with link and link is not working.

Comment: this is the default functionality.. how can you submit the data which are not listed or visible? check your gmail inbox, it works like the same..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can get all the selected check box values using following code this might be helpful for you

```
var myArray = [];
var id = "";
var oTable = $("#example").dataTable();
$(".class1:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function() {
    if (id != "") {
        id = id + "," + $(this).val();
    } else {
        id = $(this).val();
    }
});
```

Comment: No, I want to get specific selsected data from previous page too.

Comment: In above code,you have assigned value to id  but how can i appendTo(this) so can get all data i post?

Answer (score 2):

You can check them at the end.

```
var table = $("#yourtablename").DataTable({
    //your datatable options(optional)
});
```

Now jQuery have access to all the rows by following code

```
  table.$('td > input:checkbox').each(function () {
            // If checkbox is checked
            if (this.checked) {
             //Your code for example
                alert($(this).attr('name'));
            }
    });
```